# Joining key-value table to a master table

Tags: mysql, stripe-payments

I have two tables:

1. charges (1 row for each transaction)
2. charges_metadata (1 row for each key-value pair + 1 column in each row for charge_id)

My current code gives me a new row for each key in charges_metadata

```
SELECT m.id, m.amount, s.key, s.value
FROM charges AS m
INNER JOIN charges_metadata AS s ON m.id = s.charge_id
WHERE key IN ('Product', 'Plan Type', 'Payment Plan')
```

What I would like to see is:

```
+----------------+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+
|       id       | amount | Product | Plan Type | Payment Plan |
+----------------+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+
| 908asd7f098sa7 |    150 | T-shirt | Main      | Monthly      |
| 80as9d8f0as9d8 |    200 | Jeans   | Regular   | Yearly       |
+----------------+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Can you create your DDL and sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pivot out the values using the key, which requires an aggregation:

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.amount,
    MAX(CASE WHEN s.`key` = 'Product'      THEN s.value END) AS Product,
    MAX(CASE WHEN s.`key` = 'Plan Type'    THEN s.value END) AS PlanType,
    MAX(CASE WHEN s.`key` = 'Payment Plan' THEN s.value END) AS PaymentPlan
FROM charges m
INNER JOIN charges_metadata s
WHERE `key` IN ('Product', 'Plan Type', 'Payment Plan')
GROUP BY
    m.id,
    m.amount,
    s.charge_id;
```